# scala replace string with underscore joined

Tags: regex, string, scala, match

I have a general question about how to replacing string parts.

Say I have 2 Strings:

```
a = "i am going to watch game of throne tonight on my throne"
b = "game_of_throne"
```

What is the most efficient way to replace game of throne with game_of_throne (i.e adding the under score to treat it as one string subject). If I do something like regex:

```
val c = """_""".r.replaceAllIn(b," ").r
val c.replaceAllIn(a, c) How do I actually ask it to draw the underscore?
```

I am trying to avoid splitting the String since it often increases computation time by quite a lot.

EDIT: I have a million pair of these, so I need to be able to use map and variable a and b.

Comment: `string.replace("game of throne", "game_of_throne");`

Comment: `a.replaceAll(b.replaceAll("_", " "), b)`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Sorry, I have not been entirely clear, I have millions of pairs of these, I need to be able to using string representations a and b instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a.replaceAll(b.replaceAll("_", " "), b)`

Not sure if there is a more pure Scala way to do this but this should do.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can help you.

```
object TestRegular extends App{
        val  a = "i am going to watch game of throne tonight on my throne"
        val c = """game of throne""".r.replaceAllIn(a,"game_of_throne")
        println(c)
}
```